# How can I reduce the solutions returned by DSolve to a real-valued function over the reals?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to use `DSolve` in order to solve the following equation:

$\qquad \rho'' +\Omega^2 \rho -\frac{1}{\rho^3}$,

where $\rho=\rho(t)$ and $\Omega$ is a constant. I know that

$\qquad \rho = \frac{1}{\Omega} \{\frac{A^2}{E^2}\, Cos(\Omega t)^2+\frac{B^2}{E^2}Sin(\Omega t)^2) +2 (\frac{A^2}{E^2}\frac{B^2}{E^2}-\Omega^2)^{1/2} Sin(\Omega t)\,Cos(\Omega t) \}^{1/2}$

is a solution, but Mathematica does not give me this among the solution.

In particular

```
DSolve[ {ρ''[t] + Ω^2   ρ[t] - 1/(ρ[t])^3 == 0},  ρ[t], t,  
  Assumptions -> {Ω ∈ Reals  && t ∈ Reals}]
```

returns

```
{
 {ρ[t] -> -(Sqrt[E^(-4 I Ω (t + C[2])) - 4 Ω^2 + 2 E^(-2 I Ω (t + C[2])) C[1] + C[1]^2]/(2 Sqrt[E^(-2 I Ω (t + C[2]))] Ω))}, 
 {ρ[t] -> Sqrt[E^(-4 I Ω (t + C[2])) - 4 Ω^2 + 2 E^(-2 I Ω (t + C[2])) C[1] + C[1]^2]/(2 Sqrt[E^(-2 I Ω (t + C[2]))] Ω)}, 
 {ρ[t] -> -(Sqrt[E^(4 I Ω (t + C[2])) - 4 Ω^2 + 2 E^(2 I Ω (t + C[2])) C[1] + C[1]^2]/(2 Sqrt[E^(2 I Ω (t + C[2]))] Ω))}, 
 {ρ[t] -> Sqrt[E^(4 I Ω (t + C[2])) - 4 Ω^2 + 2 E^(2 I Ω (t + C[2])) C[1] + C[1]^2]/(2 Sqrt[E^(2 I Ω (t + C[2]))] Ω)}}
}
```

Note that $\Omega$ is real. I I want a real solution for $\rho$ too.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica gives a real solution, not realy obvious!!!

```
sol = DSolve[{ρ''[t] + Ω^2 ρ[t] - 1/(ρ[t])^3 == 0}, ρ[t], t,Assumptions -> {Ω ∈ Reals && t ∈ Reals}]
```

simplification by hand in 2 steps:

```
sol1 = sol // ExpToTrig
sol2=sol1 /. Sin[p_] -> I Sinh[p]

(*{{ρ[t] -> -((√(-4 Ω^2 + C[1]^2 + 
      2 C[1] Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
      Cos[4 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
      2 C[1] Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
      Sinh[4 Ω (t + 
          C[2])]))/(2 Ω Sqrt[
    Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
     Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])]]))}, 
{ρ[t] -> (√(-4 Ω^2 + C[1]^2 + 
    2 C[1] Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
    Cos[4 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
    2 C[1] Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
    Sinh[4 Ω (t + C[2])]))/(2 Ω Sqrt[
  Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
   Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])]])}, 
{ρ[t] -> -((√(-4 Ω^2 + C[1]^2 + 
      2 C[1] Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
      Cos[4 Ω (t + C[2])] - 
      2 C[1] Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])] - 
      Sinh[4 Ω (t + 
          C[2])]))/(2 Ω Sqrt[
    Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] - 
     Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])]]))}, 
 {ρ[t] -> (√(-4 Ω^2 + C[1]^2 + 
    2 C[1] Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] + 
    Cos[4 Ω (t + C[2])] - 
    2 C[1] Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])] - 
    Sinh[4 Ω (t + C[2])]))/(2 Ω Sqrt[
  Cos[2 Ω (t + C[2])] - 
   Sinh[2 Ω (t + C[2])]])}}*)
```

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to tell Mathematica to show me the solution straight in this form?

Comment: `sol // ExpToTrig /. Sin[p_] -> I Sinh[p] `